# Using bash to refresh chrome browser windows

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, google-chrome, command

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to have a bash script to auto refresh all running instances of chrome including all the tabs open in each instance? I have been looking into it and it seems as though BASH is the best solutions for the problem.

Could anybody kindly give me some guidance on how i can so something like this using BASH or any other suggested tech?

Comment: If you already researched and found that bash is a good tool for this, can you please [edit] your question and include the code you've tried? What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? Please read [ask].

Comment: Have a look at the xdotool command, you can use it to retrieve the chrome window by title, then you make it active, finally you simulate an F5 key press to refresh the browser